# Animate jquery onclick absolute position move

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to animate this 'sliderish' thing that I just made. And since i'm an infant when it comes to jquery i'm having trouble.

I thought this would work but it isn't.

```
$('ul').animate({.css('left', -600)}, "slow");
```

but obviously that isn't working

```
$('#slide-left').click(function(){
    $('ul').css('left', 0);

     return false;
});
$('#slide-right').click(function(){
     $('ul').css('left', -600);

     return false;
});
$('#back-right').click(function(){
    $('ul').css('left', -300);

     return false;
});
$('#back-left').click(function(){
    $('ul').css('left', -300);

     return false;
});
```

heres a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NePyd/3/

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong syntax for animate, it's `.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )` :

```
$('ul').animate({left: -600}, 600);
```

Check out the docs for a more comprehensive understanding of **[.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)**

**[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NePyd/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul').animate({'left':0}, "slow");
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NePyd/4/)